# How to prevent update function insert to the MongoDB from Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the Meteor.method that check the existing document.
when it does not found it insert the document,
for second time it found it update and insert.
Please help to check and fix my following code:

```
'upload': function upload(data, name, eventId) {
    const wb = XLSX.read(data, {type:'binary'});
    var checkUpdate;
    XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]]).forEach(r => {
        r.owner = this.userId,
        r.username = Meteor.user().username,
        r.updatedAt = new Date(),
        r.amount = Number(r.amount),
        r.eventid = eventId,
        r.firstname = r.firstname.trim(),
        r.lastname = r.lastname.trim(),
        Registers.findOne({ firstname: r.firstname, lastname: r.lastname, eventid: eventId }) ? 
        Registers.update({ firstname: r.firstname, lastname: r.lastname, eventid: eventId }, { $set: {updatedAt: r.updatedAt, amount: r.amount } })
        : 
        r.createdAt = new Date(),
        Registers.insert(r)
    })

    return wb;
},
```

First time, if the database is empty, it insert new document.
For second time, if it found the document it then update the document,
and also insert new document with update function not insert function.

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.registers.find({ eventid: "aZrumf45q8sBGGrY2" })
{ "_id" : "MzqD73vsgyxRTyekJ", "salution" : "Mr.", "firstname" : "qwer", "lastname" : "asdf", "gender" : "Male", "age" : "38", "province" : "chiangmai", "amount" : 1000, "owner" : "rBjWm4PRTHwAo2vRS", "username" : "mai", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-11T12:28:36.966Z"), "eventid" : "aZrumf45q8sBGGrY2", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-11T12:20:49.731Z") }
{ "_id" : "suzPhYkvQQcYjZj5p", "salution" : "Mr.", "firstname" : "abcd", "lastname" : "efgh", "gender" : "Male", "age" : "30", "province" : "chiangmai", "amount" : 500, "owner" : "rBjWm4PRTHwAo2vRS", "username" : "mai", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-11T12:28:37.017Z"), "eventid" : "aZrumf45q8sBGGrY2", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-11T12:20:49.739Z") }
{ "_id" : "QYgF7aLvBDwo5amuA", "salution" : "Mr.", "firstname" : "qwer", "lastname" : "asdf", "gender" : "Male", "age" : "38", "province" : "chiangmai", "amount" : 1000, "owner" : "rBjWm4PRTHwAo2vRS", "username" : "mai", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-11T12:28:36.966Z"), "eventid" : "aZrumf45q8sBGGrY2" }
{ "_id" : "XYSBxgiz5T9QXad6r", "salution" : "Mr.", "firstname" : "abcd", "lastname" : "efgh", "gender" : "Male", "age" : "30", "province" : "chiangmai", "amount" : 500, "owner" : "rBjWm4PRTHwAo2vRS", "username" : "mai", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-11T12:28:37.017Z"), "eventid" : "aZrumf45q8sBGGrY2" }
```

From the code, when I add twice, the second time, I lose createdAt field.
I don't know why.????

I have got it !!!! Thank you very much for all comments

```
'upload': function upload(data, name, eventId) {
    const wb = XLSX.read(data, {type:'binary'});
    var checkUpdate;
    XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]]).forEach(r => {
        if (!Registers.findOne({ firstname: r.firstname, lastname: r.lastname, eventid: eventId })) {
        r.owner = this.userId,
        r.username = Meteor.user().username,
        r.updatedAt = new Date(),
        r.amount = Number(r.amount),
        r.eventid = eventId,
        r.firstname = r.firstname.trim(),
        r.lastname = r.lastname.trim(),
        r.createdAt = new Date(),
        Registers.insert(r)
        } else {
        r.owner = this.userId,
        r.username = Meteor.user().username,
        r.updatedAt = new Date(),
        r.amount = Number(r.amount),
        r.eventid = eventId,
        r.firstname = r.firstname.trim(),
        r.lastname = r.lastname.trim(),
        Registers.update({ firstname: r.firstname, lastname: r.lastname, eventid: eventId }, { $set: {updatedAt: r.updatedAt, amount: r.amount } })
        }
    })
    return wb;
},
```

Comment: And what is your question? Does this code work or not?

Comment: "Prevent update" - based on which premise?

Comment: Hi all, I update the question. *Styx, it does not work. *Jankapunkt, I don't know what you mean. Anyway, thanks for all response.

Comment: *Jankapunkt, I just get you, I'm trying to update only updatedAt and amount but it insert new document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Collection.upsert](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-upsert) method.

Basically it modifies one or more documents in the collection, or insert one if no matching documents were found. Returns an object with keys numberAffected (the number of documents modified) and insertedId (the unique _id of the document that was inserted, if any).

Comment: *Ankur, thanks for your help but I would like to update first but if it does not match it just insert because of createdAt field.

Comment: Please post your SimpleSchema if any.

Comment: Hi Ankur, thank you very much for your help. I'm trying to use many solution and I have got it. But I think it is not a good coding.
I don't use schema, I use pure mongodb. Could you please share the solution? Please see the update solution in my edit.

Comment: What you have used is really very typical and not recommended for future code maintainance perspective. Try spending time with SimpleSchema, you will come to know that it is very easy to implement.