# How to update a document in mongo db by matching user Id if it exists and insert if does not exist using upsert in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to update a document when it matches user Id entered in Url and if it does not exist then insert it.Here in my code update is working fine but insert has some issue as i am matching _id with given to update .so is there any other way to match user Id in document with given user Id ?
Anyone help me with this issue.
Below is my code:

```
     var p = Dbs.findOne({ user_id: Router.current().params._id });
     Dbs.update({ _id: p._id }, {
       $set: {
        user_id: user_id1,
        cont: cont1,
        add: add1,
        pth: pth1
      }
    },
    {upsert:true}
    );
```

I tried using {User_id:p._id} in place of { _id: p._id } but its not working.

Comment: The synxtax is correct in order to upsert the document if the _id on your collection doesn't exists, Log the p._id to see if it match any of the document available in your collection.

Comment: No it does not match.for example:If i want to update user details with id=111 if it exists then then p._id holds value of  _id for id 111.and if 111 user id is not present  then there is nothing to in p._id.So my question is instead of compering  _id can i compare it with user Id ?

Comment: This is the iron router: Router.route('/temp1/:_id', function () {
  var pid = this.params._id;
  this.render('temp1', {
    data: function () {
      return Dbs.findOne({user_id:pid});
         
      Router.go("/temp1",{},{id:pid});
    }
  
  });
});

Comment: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148597/how-to-prevent-update-function-insert-to-the-mongodb-from-meteor/46152331#46152331

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you just want to match on `user_id` instead of `_id`. Then just use that in your selector:

```
Dbs.update({ user_id: your_user_id_value },
  {
    $set: {
      user_id: user_id1,
      cont: cont1,
      add: add1,
      pth: pth1
    }
  },
  { upsert: true}
);
```

This will work if there's only one document found. If the match finds multiple documents then only the first one will be modified unless you also specify `multi: true` in your options. Note also that this code will only work on the server.

Comment: I made changes as you suggested  @Michel Floyd but now i am not able to update nor insert. i am  getting this error :  Uncaught errorClass {isClientSafe: true, error: 403, reason: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.", details: undefined, message: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]", …}

Comment: Is this error because i am running this code on client side ? if yes then please suggest useful references on how to work on server side

Comment: This error is thrown because you do not have any permition on client side to update any code w/o referring to an _id (for safety purpose)
This code will work on the server correctly !

Comment: Okay.thanks @Rolljee .Can you suggest me any references on how to deploy on server

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by deploy on server ? But if your problem is accessing the server in the Route, you can use Meteor.call('myserverMethod', (error, result) => {. <callback function here> });